# Google Map search with MySQL and PHP and xml

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I used this article about Maps API with PHP and MySQL for a map with markers: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=nl-NL

What should I change in the code below in order to search for specific records in the database with a form instead of all records?  The function DownloadURL() uses phpsqlajax_genxml4.php which is below as well. This code contains the query $query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE vervaldatum > $vandaag"; This selects almost all but I want to do a selection. Like: WHERE heeft = 'zaden'; And this 'zaden' was filled out as search string in a form.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>GroenteRuilen - Zoeken</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="groente, ruilen, moestuin, tuin, oogst, ruil, permacultuur, eco, ruilhandel, organic, kas, volkstuin"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Platform voor het ruilen van de oogst uit je moestuin."/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

        var shadow = {
            url: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(37, 32),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(5,5),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,20)
          };

        var customIcons = {
          restaurant: {
            icon: 'images/markerWortel.png',
            shadow: shadow
          },
          bar: {
            icon: 'images/markerWortel.png',
            shadow: shadow
          }
        };

        function initialize() {
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.6, 7.0),
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
          }); 
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml4.php", function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
              var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
              var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
              var heeft = markers[i].getAttribute("heeft");
              var wil = markers[i].getAttribute("wil");
              var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");

              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
              var html = "<b>" + name + "</b><br/><font color='red'>" + address + "</font><br/>" + "<font size='-1.5'>heeft: " + heeft + "<br/>" + "wil: " + wil + "</font>";
              var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon,
                shadow: icon.shadow
              });
              bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

            }
          });
        }

        function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        }


        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
          var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
              new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
              new XMLHttpRequest;

          request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
              request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
              callback(request, request.status);
            }
          };

          request.open('GET', url, true);
          request.send(null);
        }

        function doNothing() {}
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        //]]>

      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36447642-1']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

      </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="topPanel">
<ul>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
<li class='active'>Zoeken</li>
<li><a href="meedoen.php">Ruilen</a></li>
<li><a href="uitleg.html">Uitleg</a></li>
<li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="index.html">
<div id="logo"><img src="images/logoGroenteRuilenWortel300.png" title="Home" alt="Home" width="300" height="89" border="0" /></a></div>
  <div id="headerPanelfast">
      <div id="map" style="width: 762px; height: 264px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="bodyPanel6">
    <div id="link_kaart"><a href="/kaart.html" target="_blank">Klik hier voor grotere kaart</a></div>
    <h2>Zoeken</h2>
    <p>Je kunt op de kaart kijken of er wat te ruilen aangemeld is maar dat is lastig als er veel bij jou in de buurt is. Je moet steeds klikken op een worteltje. Als je gericht wilt zoeken kan je hier opgeven wat je zoekt. Je mag ook een deel van een woord invullen. Als je bijvoorbeeld artisjokkenzaden zoekt mag je best invullen artis. 
Is het niet te vinden dan kan je het beste zelf opgeven dat je iets zoekt via  <span><a href="meedoen.php">Ruilen</a></span> en geef aan wat je wilt (en zelf hebt). Succes! En eet smakelijk!</p>
    <p class="dotline"><img src="images/blank.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" /></p>
         <div id="centreer">
             <form method="POST" action="zoeken2.php" > 
                <TABLE CELLSPACING="2" CELLPADDING="2" BORDER="0">
                Zoekwoord: <input type="text" name="zoekwoord" /> 
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Zoek" /> 
                </TABLE>
             </form> 
        </div>
</div>       

<div id="footerPanel">
  <div id="footerbodyPanel">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>| </li>
  <li><a href="wiezijnwij.html">Wie zijn wij</a> | </li>
  <li><a href="disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a>| </li>
  <li><a href="zoeken.php">Links</a> | </li>
  <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a> </li>
  </ul>
  <p class="copyright">© 2013 GroenteRuilen All rights reserved</p>
   <div id="footerhtmlPanel"><a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer" target="_blank">html</a></div>
   <div id="footercssPanel"><a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer" target="_blank">css</a></div>
   <div id="footertwitterPanel"><a href="http://twitter.com/GroenteRuilen/" target="_blank"></a></div>
   <div id="footerpinterestPanel"><a href="http://pinterest.com/groenteruilen/" target="_blank"></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

And this is phpsqlajax_genxml4.php:

```
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$vandaag = date("Ymd");
// Alleen de markers tonen met een vervaldatum in de toekomt:
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE vervaldatum > $vandaag"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("heeft", $row['heeft']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("wil", $row['wil']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("extra", $row['extra']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow this must be old. I mean why would you use xml insted of json. Why would you use my_sql functions instead of PDO or mysqli. Why would you use pure javascript when you can have the sweetness of jquery?

For the question.
You have to pass it as a parameter in your GET request.

```
downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml4.php?q=PUT_YOUR_PARAMETER_HERE", function(data)
```

and retrieve it on the server (PHP) with `$_GET['q']`

Comment: As I mentioned i have got the method by Google itself in this article. But I'll study jquery improvements. I'll use your solution. Thanks a lot alkis!

Comment: I've forgotten about this, but if my answer helped you should accept it so the question can be closed.